# Swing action listener won't listen to me

Tags: java, swing, sockets, actionlistener

I am trying to add a GUI for my java client but I am banging my head against the wall once again. What I am trying to do is send a command to my MySQL server when I click a JButton(the Shifts button) but I get an exception ("Unknown command!") that I created when anything different than the numbers 0, 1-4 is sent. Without using the GUI it was working with keyboard input(scanner, etc.). Now I am trying to pass static arguments but it seems that they can't be read properly. I will be glad if anyone could help. Here's the code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class AirlinesClient extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    JPanel Shifts;
    JButton shButt;
    JPanel AirplanesFood;
    JButton afButt;
    JPanel Pilots;
    JButton pButt;
    JPanel Schedule;
    JButton sButt;
    public static String contact;
    public AirlinesClient(){
        setTitle("Airlines");
        setSize(300,290);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void Schedule(){
        this.Schedule = new JPanel();
        Schedule.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(Schedule);
    }

    private void ScheduleButton(JPanel SchedulePanel){
        this.sButt = new JButton("Check schedules");
        this.sButt.setBounds(75, 10, 150, 50);
        SchedulePanel.add(this.sButt);
    }

    private void Pilots(){
        this.Pilots = new JPanel();
        Pilots.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(Pilots);
    }
    private void PilotsButton(JPanel PilotsPanel){
        this.pButt = new JButton ("Check pilots' shifts");
        this.pButt.setBounds(75, 70, 150, 50);
        PilotsPanel.add(this.pButt);
    }

    private void AirplanesFood(){
        this.AirplanesFood = new JPanel();
        AirplanesFood.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(AirplanesFood);
    }

    private void AirplanesButton(JPanel afPanel){
        this.afButt = new JButton ("Airplanes and Food");
        this.afButt.setBounds(75, 130, 150, 50);
        afPanel.add(this.afButt);

    }

    private void Shifts(){
        this.Shifts = new JPanel();
        Shifts.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(Shifts);
    }

    private void ShiftsButton(JPanel ShiftsPanel){
        this.shButt = new JButton ("Possible shift changes");
        this.shButt.setBounds(75, 190, 150, 50);
        shButt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                  contact = "1";
              }
            });
            this.shButt.setToolTipText("Check wheter shift changes are possible");
        ShiftsPanel.add(this.shButt);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AirlinesClient());
        Socket connection = null;
        BufferedReader socketIn = null;
        PrintWriter socketOut = null;
        int port = 1234;
        String host = "localhost";
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            try{
            connection = new Socket(host,port);
            socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            socketOut = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),true);
        }catch(ConnectException e){
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the host!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to the server!");
        String command;
        command = AirlinesClient.contact;
        do{
            socketOut.flush();
            socketOut.println(command);
            String breakline;

            while (!(breakline =socketIn.readLine()).equals("$$$")){
                System.out.println(breakline);
            }

        }while((command = keyIn.nextLine())!="0");


        System.out.println("Closing connection to server!");

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
           try{
               if(socketIn!=null) socketIn.close();
               if(socketOut!=null) socketOut.close();
               if(connection!=null) connection.close();
             }
             catch(IOException e){
               System.err.println("Socket could not be closed!");
             }
           }

    }
    public void run() {
        this.Schedule();
        this.ScheduleButton(this.Schedule);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.Pilots();
        this.PilotsButton(this.Pilots);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.AirplanesFood();
        this.AirplanesButton(this.AirplanesFood);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.Shifts();
        this.ShiftsButton(this.Shifts);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

I would be glad if you could also tell me a way to print the information I should receive from the server(as a string) into a new text field(placed in a new JFrame).
Here's what's on the server side:

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Airlines {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket connection = null;
  int port = 1234;
  try{
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   while ((connection = serverSocket.accept())!=null){
   System.out.println("Client connected!");
   Thread client = new Thread (new AirlinesThread(connection));
   client.start();
   }
  }catch (IOException e){
   System.out.println("Binding unsuccesful...");
  }
 }

}
class AirlinesThread implements Runnable{
Socket connection = null;
public AirlinesThread (Socket connection){
 this.connection = connection;
}
private static Connection connect(String url, String user, String password){
    Connection result = null;
    try{
      result = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      System.out.println("Database connection successful!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("Could not connect to the database!");
    }
    return result;
  }
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Airlines";
 String user = "root";
 String pass = "123456";
 Connection link = AirlinesThread.connect(url, user, pass);
 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet resultSet = null;
 public void run() {
  PrintWriter socketOut = null;
  Scanner socketIn = null;
  try{
  socketOut = new PrintWriter(this.connection.getOutputStream(),true);
  socketIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.connection.getInputStream())));
  String command;
  socketOut.flush();
  loop:do{
   socketOut.flush();
   command = socketIn.nextLine();
   switch (command){
   case "1":
     try{
          stmt = link.createStatement();
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select Flight.id, Flight.Date, Flight.Time, Flight.Total_Flight_Time, Airports.Departure, Airports.Arrivals FROM Flight, Airports WHERE Flight.id = Airports.Flight");
          socketOut.flush();
          socketOut.println("FlightID\tDate\t\tTime\t\tTotal Time\tDeparture\tArrivals");
          while (resultSet.next()) {
           socketOut.println(resultSet.getString("Flight.id")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getDate("Flight.Date")+"\t"+resultSet.getString("Flight.Time")+"\t"+resultSet.getString("Flight.Total_Flight_Time")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Airports.Departure")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Airports.Arrivals"));
           
          }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("Something went wrong at 1");
        }
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("\nSelect from the options below:\n1: Check schedules\n2: Check pilots shifts\n3: Check corresponding airplanes and food offered\n4: Possible pilot shift changes\n0: Exit");
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("$$$");
    break;
   case "2":
    try{
          stmt = link.createStatement();
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select Flight.id, Flight.Date, Flight.Time, Pilots.First_Name, Pilots.Last_Name from Flight RIGHT JOIN Pilots ON Flight.id = Pilots.FlightID;");
          socketOut.flush();
          socketOut.println("FlightID\tDate\t\tTime\t\tFirst Name\tLast Name");
          while (resultSet.next()) { 
         socketOut.flush();
           socketOut.println(resultSet.getString("Flight.id")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getDate("Flight.Date")+"\t"+resultSet.getString("Flight.Time")+"\t"+resultSet.getString("Pilots.First_Name")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Pilots.Last_Name"));
          }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("Something went wrong at 2");
        }
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("\nSelect from the options below:\n1: Check schedules\n2: Check pilots shifts\n3: Check corresponding airplanes and food offered\n4: Possible pilot shift changes\n0: Exit");
     socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    break;
   case "3":  
    String FlightID;
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Select your Flight ID: ");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    command = socketIn.nextLine();
    FlightID = command;
    try{     
          stmt = link.createStatement();
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Airplanes.Plane_Model, Food.Breakfast, Food.Lunch, Food.Dinner FROM Airplanes JOIN Flight ON Airplanes.FlightID = Flight.id JOIN Food ON Flight.id = Food.FlightID WHERE Flight.id = "+FlightID+";");  
          if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
           socketOut.flush();
           socketOut.println("You've entered wrong FlightID!");
          }
          while (resultSet.next()) {
           socketOut.flush();
           socketOut.println(resultSet.getString("Airplanes.Plane_Model")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Food.Breakfast")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Food.Lunch")+"\t\t"+resultSet.getString("Food.Dinner"));
           
          }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("Something went wrong at 3");
        }
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("\nSelect from the options below:\n1: Check schedules\n2: Check pilots shifts\n3: Check corresponding airplanes and food offered\n4: Possible pilot shift changes\n0: Exit");
     socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    break;
    
   case "4":
    String FirstName=null;
    String LastName=null;
    Date date1 = new Date();
    Date date2 = new Date();
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Please enter the First name of the pilot to be replaced: ");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    command = socketIn.nextLine();
    FirstName = command;
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Please enter the Last name of the pilot to be replaced: ");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    command = socketIn.nextLine();
    LastName = command;
    String FirstName1=null;
    String LastName1=null;
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Please enter the First name of the pilot to take the shift: ");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    command = socketIn.nextLine();
    FirstName1 = command;
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Please enter the Last name of the pilot to take the shift: ");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    command = socketIn.nextLine();
    LastName1 = command;
    int id1 = 0;
    int id2 = 0;

    try{     
          stmt = link.createStatement();
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("Select Flight.Date, Pilots.First_Name, Pilots.Last_name, Pilots.FlightID FROM Flight, Pilots WHERE Flight.id=Pilots.FlightID and Pilots.First_Name="+"\""+FirstName+"\""+"and Pilots.Last_Name="+"\""+LastName+"\""+";");          
          if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
           socketOut.flush();
           socketOut.println("You've entered a wrong name!");
          }
          while (resultSet.next()) {
           date1 = resultSet.getDate("Flight.Date");
           id1 = resultSet.getShort("Pilots.FlightID");
           
          }
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("Select Flight.Date, Pilots.First_Name, Pilots.Last_name, Pilots.FlightID FROM Flight, Pilots WHERE Flight.id=Pilots.FlightID and Pilots.First_Name="+"\""+FirstName1+"\""+"and Pilots.Last_Name="+"\""+LastName1+"\""+";"); 
          if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
           socketOut.flush();
           socketOut.println("You've entered another wrong name!");
          }
          while (resultSet.next()) {
           
            date2 = resultSet.getDate("Flight.Date");
            id2 = resultSet.getShort("Pilots.FlightID");
            if (date1.equals(date2)){
             socketOut.flush();
                socketOut.println("Both pilots have a flight at the same date or are on the same flight.");
                socketOut.println(FirstName+" "+LastName+"is on flight "+id1+", "+FirstName1+" "+LastName1+"is on flight "+id2+".");
            }
             
            else {
             socketOut.flush();
                socketOut.println(FirstName+" "+LastName+" can be replaced by "+FirstName1+" "+LastName1+"."); 
            }
           }
          
          
          
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("Something went wrong at 4");
        }
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("\nSelect from the options below:\n1: Check schedules\n2: Check pilots shifts\n3: Check corresponding airplanes and food offered\n4: Possible pilot shift changes\n0: Exit");
     socketOut.flush();
     socketOut.println("$$$");
    break;
   case "0" :
    socketOut.flush();
    socketOut.println("Exitting...");
    break loop;
   default:
    System.out.println("Unknown command!");
    socketOut.println("Unknown command!");
    socketOut.println("$$$");
    break;
   }
  }while(command!="0");
  System.out.println("Closing connection to the client!");
  }catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
          try{
            if (socketIn!=null) socketIn.close();
            if (socketOut!=null) socketOut.close();
            if (connection!=null) connection.close();
            System.out.println("Connection to server closed!");
          }
          catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Could not close connection!");
          }
 }
  try{
   if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
   if(resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
         if(link != null) link.close();
         System.out.println("Database connection closed successfully!");
  }catch(SQLException ex){
   System.out.println("Could not close connection to the database!");
  }  
  }
}
```

So far I managed to send text to the Server and get a console answer from it but my problem now is that I can't add anything else than this "Schedule" button. Whatever I try to add is not visible or it replaces the button. Any ideas?

```html
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AirlinesClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 public static BufferedReader socketIn = null;
 public static PrintWriter socketOut = null;
 public static Socket connection = null;
 public static String breakline;
 public static String command;
 private static void initGUI() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

  JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Airlines Client");
  JPanel schPanel = new JPanel();
  JButton Schedules  = new JButton ("Flight Schedules");
  JTextField schedArea = new JTextField("HI",20);
//mainFrame
    mainFrame.setSize(300, 400);
    mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
       mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       mainFrame.setVisible(true);
//adding ScheduleButton's panel to the root frame
       schPanel.setLayout(null);
       mainFrame.getContentPane().add(schPanel);
//Adding Schedule button
       Schedules.setBounds(75, 10, 150, 50);
       Schedules.setVisible(true);
       schPanel.add(Schedules);
//Adding action on click
       Schedules.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            socketOut.println("1");
   }
  });
       

       
 
       
 }

 
 
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
  
  initGUI();
  
  int port = 1234;
  String host = "localhost";
  connection = new Socket(host,port);
  socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
  socketOut = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),true);
  
  try{ 
  System.out.println("Successfully connected to the server!");
  do{
   
   
   
   while (!(breakline =socketIn.readLine()).equals("$$$")){
    System.out.println(breakline);
   }
   
  }while(command!="0");
  System.out.println("Closing connection to server!");
 }catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 } finally{
        try{
            if(socketIn!=null) socketIn.close();
            if(socketOut!=null) socketOut.close();
            if(connection!=null) connection.close();
          }
          catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Socket could not be closed!");
          }
        }
  
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
 
 
}
```

Comment: This will fail: `command = keyIn.nextLine()) != "0"` since you shouldn't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here. Also, your code is not how a Swing application, or any application for that matter, should communicate over sockets. Don't use a static field that the GUI changes, but rather ...

Comment: have the GUI send appropriate information out on the socket when an event dictates that something should be sent, and have it read in information from the Socket in a background thread, one that notifies the GUI of changes.

Comment: Also, if you're code is generating exceptions or errors, please show them with your original question, and also indicate which line(s) are involved in causing them. Also, you state that you're sending info to a MySQL server, but I see no such code above.

Comment: Also, while null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Will try what you said. And the code is not generating any error it is just checking whether my input is between the numbers 1 and 4.

Comment: Also your server code has `while(command!="0");` which again will fail. You should change `System.out.println("Unknown command!");` to `System.out.println("Unknown command: " + command);` so you know what is being sent in error.

Comment: Changed the sever code with equalsIgnoreCase("0") and the error I get printed is "null" as an unknown command at AirlinesClient.main(AirlinesClient.java:118) which is ... "while(command.equalsIgnoreCase("0")); "

Comment: @GeorgiHristov: yeah, I guessed it was null before you posted this comment after re-reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely repeatedly sending out in your socketOut `null` since you're getting extracting `contact` from your AirlinesClient only once, at the beginning of the program, when its null, and then are repeatedly sending it over the socket.

Again, I'd change the entire code's structure:

- Make contact a non-static variable
- Pass the Socket into the GUI
- Call println on the Socket only when needed -- here in the button's ActionListener.
- Read from the Socket in a SwingWorker background thread, and publish the results to the GUI using the SwingWorker's publish/process method pair.

Comment: Well I am new to the whole Swing idea and am having trouble implementing the Swing to the server thread. It seems though I will have to dig deeper in the Swing documentation. The way I designed the GUI seems odd even to me but I can't figure out a different way.

Comment: @GeorgiHristov: it will take a lot of study and the writing of a lot of code to get familiar with any new library. Fortunately there are some great tutorials out there, including [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).